# Passing data from sqlitedatabase to a Detailview

Tags: ios

---

I'm creating an iOS app which is a directory system, where on the first page I load data such as a list of some states in a tableview (from a sqlite database). When clicking on a state only the districts under that particular state have to be displayed in the detailview's tableview. My problem is that when clicking on each district the phonenumber of that district must be shown in the next view controller. Can somebody please help?

This is the firstview.

```
@implementation firstview
@synthesize ddetails=_ddetails;
@synthesize at,arraydata,show,table;
static firstview *_database;
+ (firstview*)database {
if (_database == nil) {
    _database = [[firstview alloc] init];
}
return _database;}


 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

        return [theauthors count];
}
   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return 30;}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

menu *me = [self.theauthors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text=me.state;
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
    [_button setTitle:cellText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    menu *infos=[theauthors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.ddetails =  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailViewController"] ;
    _ddetails.uniqueId=infos.id;
   // NSLog(@"%@",infos.state);
   // NSLog(@"%d",infos.id);
          [self.navigationController pushViewController:_ddetails animated:NO];
        }

-(NSMutableArray *) authorList{
theauthors = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init] ;
show=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
@try {
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath   ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"menu.sqlite"];
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

    }
    NSString *query =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id,category FROM  category "];

    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [query UTF8String], -1, &selectstmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }else{

        while (sqlite3_step(selectstmt)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            menu * men = [[menu alloc] init];
            men.id= sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt,0);
            men.state=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,1)];
            [theauthors addObject:men];
           // NSLog(@"%@",men.category);

           // NSLog(@"%d",men.id);
        }
    }
}

@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
@finally {
         sqlite3_close(db);
    return theauthors;
}

}
- (detailsnews *)Detailsnews:(int)uniqueId{
NSLog(@"%d",uniqueId);
detailsnews *get=nil;
_the=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
_gets=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
@try {
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"menu.sqlite"];
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

    }
    NSString *sqls =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM  menulist where category=%d",uniqueId];

   // NSLog(@"%d",uniqueId);
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt6;


    if(sqlite3_prepare(db, [sqls UTF8String], -1, &selectstmt6, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }else{


        while (sqlite3_step(selectstmt6)==SQLITE_ROW) {
           // NSLog(@"%d",uniqueid);
          int totalValue = 0;
            int uniqueId = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt6,0);
          //  NSLog(@"%d",uniqueid);
           [_gets addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:uniqueId]];
            for(NSNumber *number in _gets) // Use fast enumeration to iterate through the array
                {
                  totalValue = [number intValue];
                // NSLog(@"%d",totalValue);

                 }
            char *nameChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt6, 2);
            NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:nameChars];
            char *rec = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt6, 1);
            NSString *rece = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:rec];
          //  NSLog(@"%@",rece);
           [_the addObject:rece];
           NSMutableString * result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            for (NSObject * obj in _the)
                 {
                 [result appendString:[obj description]];
                  result = [_the componentsJoinedByString: @"\r"];
                // NSLog(@"%@",result);
                 }
            //[_the addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:uniqueid]];
           // int totalValue = 0;
           // for(NSNumber *number in _the) // Use fast enumeration to iterate through the array
           // {
              //  totalValue = [number intValue];
               // NSLog(@"%d",totalValue);

           // }
           //
         //   NSMutableString * result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
           // int totalValue = 0;

            //for (NSObject * obj in _the)
           // {
           // [result appendString:[obj description]];
            //  result = [_the componentsJoinedByString: @"\r"];

               // NSLog(@"%@",result);

           // }
                            //NSArray *arr=[result componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r"];
           // NSMutableString * vgh = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
           // for (NSObject * obj in arr)
           // {
                //[vgh appendString:[obj description]];
               // vgh = [arr componentsJoinedByString: @"\r"];

                         // }

            get = [[detailsnews alloc] initWithUniqueId:totalValue district:result phonenumber:name ];
            //NSLog(@"%@",_the);

        }

        }
}
 @catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
@finally {
     sqlite3_close(db);
    return get;
}

}
```

### detailview controller

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


        detailsnews *details = [[firstview database]
Detailsnews:_uniqueId];

    if (details != nil) {
        NSArray *arrComponents = [details.district componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r"];
        arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(int i = 0; i < [arrComponents count] ;i++)
        {
        NSString *str = [arrComponents objectAtIndex:i];

        [arr addObject:str];



-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

return [arr count];
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath     {
return 30;}
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
detailsnews *details = [[firstview database]
Detailsnews:_uniqueId];
cell.textLabel.text=[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
[button2 setTitle:cellText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
detailsnews *details = [[firstview database]

                        Detailsnews:_uniqueId];
//NSLog(@"%d",details.uniqueId);
   // NSLog(@"%@",details.rece);
    // detailsnews *infos=[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.ddetails =  [self.storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"phonelistViewController"] ;
  _ddetails.uniqueId=details.uniqueId;
   // NSLog(@"%d",details.uniqueId);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_ddetails animated:NO];
    }
```

Comment: Did u mange to pull data from db successfully?

Comment: yes i can retreive successfully all the datas from db except the last part ie when clicking on each district the ph:num is repeating for all the districts of a particular state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Pass the data including the phoneNumbers from first stateViewController to District and then from District to DetailsPage…I would suggest pass an NSdictionary which Includes the data from one view to another such as..In second ViewController declare a global Dictionary as mainDictionary..

and in didSelectRowAtIndexPath just pass the data as

```
 self.ddetails =  [self.storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"phonelistViewController"] ;
  _ddetails.mainDict=AllThe Details;
```

Do the same thing with PhoneNumbers also

Comment: But when passing districts id from district view controller to detail page the same id is passing to all districts.if i select one state from state's table then it goes to districts table containing only the  data of that particular state but for all the districts the same phonenumber of the last entered districts in the database is displaying.

Comment: Check Your data Object, I guess you data has something to do with it

Comment: thanku for ur reply.i think that data is geting replaced when the while loop is excecuting and therefore only the last value is geting retreived from the database.i've the same issue when i try to display the data in the district table only the last district is geting displayed but i solved it by puting it in an array.

Comment: if i get the id of each district only then i can be able to pass the phonenumber.but the problem is that only the last districts id is passed to the detail page.

Comment: you may have to Map the ditrictID's with the district Names, for e.g.: if you have an array with district name the you better map that array with a another containing the mapped district ID..or make up an array of dictionaries including both such as…
[
  {
    districtName:"";
    districtId:"";
   },...
]

Comment: but how will i pass it to the detail page.